# Meaning of "Qualité" on a form?

Tags: vocabulaire, terminologie

I am filling out an application for scientific grant, it asks me to fill in some details about my doctorate:

```
   Nom de votre directeur de thèse  .......
Prénom de votre directeur de thèse  .......
                           Qualité  .......
```

Does “*Qualité*” mean title, i.e. Professor, Doctor etc.? Or something else?

Is it because there is a distinction between a civil title and professional title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and either one of the two answers below is expected:

- Professor
- Doctor, HDR

In the latter, HDR[1] means that he/she can supervise researches.

There is no relation with any civil title. It is more in the meaning of `function as`.

[1] HDR is the highest University french diploma. Usually, people obtain it after their Ph.D. People having an HDR can be `Directeur de thèse`. They can also apply on `Professor` position, provided that they get qualified first.

Comment: It is worth noting that HDR is the abbreviation of _habilité à diriger des recherches_.

Answer (score 3):

This usage corresponds to the one described in section *C.c.* of the TLF's entry for [*Qualité*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/qualit%C3%A9). Roughly here the *qualité* would be the ground that allowed your advisor to supervise your PhD. But it could be a title, a status, a position… it is not obvious to tell what exactly *qualité* is referring to.

In this case, the denomination of his/her position is most probably expected. In universities, usual options are *Professeur* (also used for any foreign teaching position) or *Directeur de recherches*. But it could also be *Maître de conférences* or *Chargé de recherche*, etc., in special cases.